# How to extend duration of the the one time login link?

Tags: users

Is it possible to change the valid duration time of the one time login link that is send out by mail to the new user? I think by default it is 24 hours, ist it possible to change this to 72 hours?

Comment: in your settings.php try adding this
$conf['user_password_reset_timeout'] = '259200';

Comment: @arpitr You'd better write this as an answer so that you get the points.

Comment: added as answer also :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Drupal 7: In your `settings.php` try adding this:

`$conf['user_password_reset_timeout'] = '259200';`

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8, you need to add the following line to your settings.php file:

`$config['user.settings']['password_reset_timeout'] = 259200;`

See the [documentation for Global overrides](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-override-system):

> Drupal 8 retains the possibility of using the global $config overrides. The configuration system integrates these override values via the Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory::get() implementation. When you retrieve a value from configuration, the global $config variable gets a chance to change the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

One can do the same in Drupal 8 via Drush too.

- To get the current setting by default it is 86400 sec means 1 day

  ```bash
  drush config:get user.settings password_reset_timeout
  ```
- To change the reset timeout duration for 2 weeks

  ```bash
  drush config:set user.settings password_reset_timeout 1209600
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use [User Password Reset Link Timeout](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_pwreset_timeout) module.